Access Point ip address is different in Web UI than what router shows
I have an Edgerouter X as router and a Fritzbox as access point. The ER-X shows a different ip address for the fritzbox than what the fritzbox itself show in its own network settings. Also the fritzbox web-ui is not reachable via the ip that ER-X is showing.
For example in my case
The DHCP Lease (inside ER-X UI) shows the access points ip address as 192.168.1.42
The AP web-ui is accessible (only with devices directly connected to it) via the ip 192.168.188.1
Should it be like that? I cant reach the Access Points UI with my Computer that is connected to the router, should it be also accessible from there?

it sounds like the fritzbox is acting as a router, not an access point.  if you aren't intentionally trying to have two networks, then try reconfiguring it into AP mode

yes you were right! Unfortunately the fritzbox's docs weren't very specific about the configurations. But I got it working now and also see all Wifi devices in the edgerouter settings. Thanks for your help
